# Change button text vertical alignment by clicking another button

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, vertical-alignment

I got two buttons, lets call them buttonA and buttonB.

What i want to achieve is when i click buttonB, i want both buttonA and buttonB to change the vertical alignment of the text inside of them.

I've tried the following:

```
func changeAllign() {
     buttonA.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignment.Top
     buttonB.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignment.Bottom
}
```

This doesn't work for some reason. When i click buttonB it will align its text to the bottom, but buttonA will stay the same. Then if i hold/or click buttonA, the text aligns to the top.

Can this be done so it changing without me having to click it first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to tell explicitly the buttons to re-layout their subviews after changing the content alignment:

```
func changeAllign() {
     buttonA.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignment.Top
     buttonA.setNeedsLayout()
     buttonB.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignment.Bottom
     buttonB.setNeedsLayout()
}
```

Comment: Sadly this does not fix the problem, still doesn't align the content till after i clicked buttonA

Comment: Eh. Sorry :/ maybe try with `setNeedsLayout`.

Comment: Perfect! that did it! Thanks mate!